# Why is my program having a longer runtime, when it should have a shorter one?

Tags: java, matrix, iteration, fibonacci, exponentiation

I have two programs to calculate the nth term in the Fibonacci Sequence as specified by the user.
The first program is as so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Fibonacci
{
    // main(String[]) - Bulk of the program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long lStartTime;
        long lFinishTime;
        long lTotalTime;
        long l;
        long lInput = 0L;
        long lToGoTo = 0L;
        String strInput;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        BigInteger biNMinusOne = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger biN = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger biHeld;
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;

        try
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter which term of the Fibonacci Sequence you would like: ");
            lInput = keyboard.nextLong();
            lToGoTo = lInput - 1L;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(lInput != 0)
        {
            for(l = 0; l < lToGoTo; l++)
            {
                biHeld = biNMinusOne.add(biN);
                biNMinusOne = biN;
                biN = biHeld;
                System.out.print(l + "\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            biN = BigInteger.ZERO;
        }
        System.out.print(lInput + "\n");
        lFinishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lTotalTime = lFinishTime - lStartTime;
        System.out.print("\nTotal Computation Time: " + lTotalTime + "ms\n");

        try
        {
            fw = new FileWriter("Fibonacci.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(df.format(biN).toString());
            bw.close();
            System.out.print("\nSee \"Fibonacci.txt\" to see the result.\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nError!\n");
        }
    }// End main(String[])
}//end Fibonacci
```

and calculates the nth term through Iteration.

My second program is as so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

/**
 * Documentation:
 * Fibonacci Identity A^n = n+1 n
 *                          n n-1
 * where for n = 1    A^1 = 1   1
 *                          1   0
 * and/or where n corresponds to the nth Fibonacci term
 * and where if the user inputs n, the n+1 term in the n-1 exponentiation of A will
 * be the requested term
 */
public class Fibonacci
{
    // main(String[]) - Bulk of the program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long l;
        long lStart;
        long lFinish;
        long lInput = 0L;
        long lTerm = 0L;
        BigInteger biN = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger[][] rgbiN  = new BigInteger[2][2];
        BigInteger[][] rgbiFibonacci = {{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE}, 
                                       {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO}};
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;

        try
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter which term of the Fibonacci Sequence you would like: ");
            lInput = keyboard.nextLong();
            lTerm = lInput - 2;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        lStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        rgbiN = rgbiFibonacci;
        if(lTerm != -1)
        {
            for(l = 0; l < lTerm; l++)
            {
                rgbiN = multiplyMatrix(rgbiN);
                System.out.print(l + "\n");
            }
            biN = rgbiN[0][0];
            System.out.print(l + "\n");
        }
        lFinish = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStart;
        System.out.print("\nTotal Computation Time: " + lFinish + "ms\n");

        try
        {
            fw = new FileWriter("Fibonacci.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(df.format(biN).toString());
            bw.close();
            System.out.print("\nSee \"Fibonacci.txt\" to see the result.\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nError!\n");
        }
    }// End main(String[])

    public static BigInteger[][] multiplyMatrix(BigInteger[][] n)
    {
        BigInteger biA;
        BigInteger biB;
        BigInteger biC;
        BigInteger biD;
        BigInteger[][] rgbiN = new BigInteger[2][2];
        BigInteger[][] rgbiFibonacci = {{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE}, 
                                       {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO}};
        biA = ((n[0][0].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[0][0])).add(n[0][1].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[1][0])));
        biB = ((n[0][0].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[0][1])).add(n[0][1].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[1][1])));
        biC = ((n[1][0].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[0][0])).add(n[1][1].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[1][0])));
        biD = ((n[1][0].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[0][1])).add(n[1][1].multiply(rgbiFibonacci[1][1])));

        rgbiN[0][0] = biA;
        rgbiN[0][1] = biB;
        rgbiN[1][0] = biC;
        rgbiN[1][1] = biD;

        return (rgbiN);
    }//end multiplyMatrix(int[][], int[][])
}//end Fibonacci
```

and calculates the sequence through Matrix Exponentiation.

The problem that I'm having is that if I run the first program for the nth term, I have a short runtime than if I run the second program for the same nth term; this goes against everything that I've read about matrix exponentiation being faster. It also has a slower runtime than a program doing matrix exponentiation I found/compiled/edited to test its runtime against my own. What am I doing wrong? Any input in either program I'll be ecstatic about; I'm more curious about why the runtime of the second program is greater than the runtime of the first, however.

I have a feeling I screwed up and basically re-implemented the Iterative method using matrix exponentiation...

*Excuse the use of Hungarian notation; this was an expansion of an assignment I did in class where I was required to use it.*

UPDATE 11/22/2015: NEW CODE

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    // main(String[]) - Bulk of the program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long lStart;
        long lFinish;
        long lNTerm = 0;
        BigInteger biF;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;

        try
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter which term of the Fibonacci Sequence you would like: ");
            lNTerm = keyboard.nextLong();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        lStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        biF = calculateNumber(lNTerm);
        lFinish = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStart;
        System.out.print("\nTotal Computation Time: " + lFinish + "ms\n");

        try
        {
            fw = new FileWriter("Fibonacci.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(df.format(biF).toString());
            bw.close();
            System.out.print("\nSee \"Fibonacci.txt\" to see the result.\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nError!\n");
        }
    }// End main(String[])

    public static BigInteger calculateNumber(long nTerm)
    {
        BigInteger[][] rgbiA = {{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE},
                               {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO}};
        BigInteger rgbiR = BigInteger.ZERO;
        if(nTerm > 0)
        {
            rgbiA = exponential(rgbiA, nTerm-1);
            rgbiR = rgbiA[0][0];
        }   
        return (rgbiR);
    }//end calculateNumber(long)

    public static BigInteger[][] exponential(BigInteger[][] fibonacciMatrix, long nTerm)
    {
        long l;
        BigInteger[][] rgbiFibonacci = {{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE},
                                       {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO}};
        for(l = 0; l < nTerm-1; l++)
        {
            rgbiFibonacci = multiplyMatrix(fibonacciMatrix, rgbiFibonacci);
        }
        return (rgbiFibonacci);
    }//end exponential(BigInteger[][], long)

    public static BigInteger[][] multiplyMatrix(BigInteger[][] x, BigInteger[][] y)
    {
        BigInteger biA;
        BigInteger biB;
        BigInteger biC;
        BigInteger biD;
        BigInteger[][] rgbiR = new BigInteger[2][2];

        biA = ((x[0][0].multiply(y[0][0])).add(x[0][1].multiply(y[1][0])));
        biB = ((x[0][0].multiply(y[0][1])).add(x[0][1].multiply(y[1][1])));
        biD = ((x[1][0].multiply(y[0][1])).add(x[1][1].multiply(y[1][1])));

        rgbiR[0][0] = biA;
        rgbiR[0][1] = biB;
        rgbiR[1][0] = biB;
        rgbiR[1][1] = biD;

        return (rgbiR);
    }//end multiplyMatrix(BigInteger[][], BigInteger[][])
}//end Fibonacci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're still doing linear amount of operations — your matrix power calculation is `O(N)`. To achieve better performance you need to reimplement power function, so it'll be [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Moreover, on small values of N performance can be nearly the same due to complexity of operations on `BigInteger`, memory allocations, functions calls and so on.

When `N` will be big enough, complexity of algorithm will still be something more than pure `O(log(N))`, because multiplication itself will be done not in `O(1)`, but `O(l^2)`, when `l` is the length (in digits) of matrix element.

So, your power function should look like this:

```
public static BigInteger[][] exponential(BigInteger[][] fibonacciMatrix, long nTerm)
{
    long l;
    BigInteger[][] rgbiFibonacci = {{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO},
            {BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}};
    while (nTerm > 0) {
        if (nTerm % 2 == 1) {
            rgbiFibonacci = multiplyMatrix(rgbiFibonacci, fibonacciMatrix);
        }
        fibonacciMatrix = multiplyMatrix(fibonacciMatrix, fibonacciMatrix);
        nTerm /= 2;
    }
    return (rgbiFibonacci);
}//end exponential(BigInteger[][], long)
```

Comment: I added a new block of code. Is this more like it should be, or am I still misinterpreting the concept?

Comment: Also, it has a quicker runtime then the first program for smaller values (e.g. n < 100000) but a larger runtime than the first program for large values... Any reason why?

Comment: @LoganHartman please see update to my answer, I've posted code sample. If you have any additional questions about algorithm, feel free to ask (but check the wikipedia link first :) )

Comment: Would you mind explaining the logic behind the while loop? Not the code itself; I've looked on Wikipedia and on different coding forums. I somewhat understand the concept, but I would prefer to understand what I'm doing rather than just say "Well, it works." and go on.

Comment: Okay, so we need to calculate x^y. We can represent y as binary, say y = y1 + y2 + y3, where y1, y2 and y3 is power of two. Then x^y == x^y1 * x^y2 * x^y3. There'll be no more multipliers than number of digits in y binary representation — log(y). Fortunately we can easily move from x^z to x^2z by one square operation. So, we are calculating x^1, x^2, x^4 and so on. In while loop we are doing this calculations and accumulating the result — if our power have 1 at nth bit, we are multiplying result by x^(2^n). That's it.

Comment: I think I understand. Essentally, you're breaking it from one repetitive calculation (i.e. n^2) to two independent repetitive calculations (n^y) where the second (y) is all based of powers of 2 (y = (a x a) ^ x; y = (2a)^x). Basically it's an equation operating in two different "counters" simultaneously. Meaning that the mod2 == 1 comes from whether the current iteration of n is applicable to the first operation or not. Am I correct in what I said or no?